# Not showing user after Migration Assistant?

Tags: macos, migration

I used Migration Assistant to transfer a user account from one MacBook to another.

However, the user that got migrated is not available as a login option on the new Macbook?

If I go into settings I can see the user account is there.   And if I change it to auto-login using the new migrated account that works.

But if I don't use auto-login I can't login with this migrated user.  Also, I can't do fast-user switching to this new user either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you happen to have FileVault enabled on the target (new) machine before initiating migration assistant?  I've run into where I needed to go into the FileVault section of the security system preferences and explicitly enable the migrated user before they would appear as a login option...